# Data contract serialization and backward and forward compatibility

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api

In a C# project, I am using Data Contract serialization in a web api for a complex entity.
Which is a good strategy  to maintain backward and forward compatibility when creating or changing the serializable type?
For example, I could add some new properties or to change some field names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remembering a few things can help, these are general for any serialisation in just about any language:

1. Start with the length, that way your code can always get the records even if it doesn't understand all of them.
2. Include a version number for the format - that way if you do have to break compatibility you can handle it gracefully.
3. Always extend enums at the end - **never** at the start or in the middle.
4. Add new fields at the end only.
5. If you have to have any variable length fields then store the length separately before the field or as the first byte in the field.
6. Allow for different integer lengths and byte ordering, by using fixed length integers with the byte order specified.
7. Try to avoid bitfields - the bit ordering & padding is often undefined.
8. Don't assume **anything**!
9. Write everything down and publish it.
10. Write it down **first** then try doing it then if necessary correct what is written.
11. Test, Test, Test - have revision tests written and available preferably cross platform, cross version, cross language.
12. Allow for the future, e.g. Unicode, new architectures, etc.
13. Look at what others have done and learn from it.

Adding a couple of links MSDN specific to C#/VB/.Net resulting from the OPs comments to preserve the links - [Data Contract Versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731138%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) & [Best Practices: Data Contract Versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733832%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - *Note that these links are subject to the vagaries of MSDN so may evaporate or move*.

Comment: Thank you. With your explanation I have found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731138%28v=vs.110%29.aspx that it precisely that I needed.